# iOS Mach-O – Make __TEXT segment temporarily writable

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, mach-o

I've tried a lot to finally get this working, but it still doesn't work yet.
Im trying to change some variables in the __TEXT section, which is read-only by default, like changing the cryptid (and other stuff)

It kind of worked a while ago, back on 32 bit devices. But somehow, it always fails after I used the 64bit commands.

It currently crashes if I hit the following lines:
`tseg->maxprot = tseg->initprot = VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE`
or
`crypt->cryptid = 1`.

```c
    struct mach_header_64* mach = (struct mach_header_64*) _dyld_get_image_header(0);

    uint64_t header_size = 0;

    struct encryption_info_command_64 *crypt;
    struct segment_command_64 *tseg;
    struct dylib_command *protector_cmd;


    // clean up some commands
    void *curloc = (void *)mach + sizeof(struct mach_header);
    for (int i=0;i<mach->ncmds;i++) {
        struct load_command *lcmd = curloc;
        if (lcmd->cmd == LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO_64) {
            // save crypt cmd
            crypt = curloc;
        } else if (lcmd->cmd == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
            struct segment_command_64 *seg = curloc;
            if (seg->fileoff == 0 && seg->filesize != 0) {
                header_size = seg->vmsize;
                tseg = curloc;
            }
        }
        if(i == mach->ncmds-1){
            protector_cmd = curloc;
        }
        curloc += lcmd->cmdsize;
    }
    kern_return_t err;

    // make __TEXT temporarily writable
    err = vm_protect(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)mach, (vm_size_t)header_size, false, VM_PROT_ALL);
    if (err != KERN_SUCCESS) exit(1);

    // modify the load commands
    // change protection of __TEXT segment
    tseg->maxprot = tseg->initprot = VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE;

    // change cryptid
    crypt->cryptid = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in changing the load command. The load commands were already processed when the program was loaded (which must be before this code of yours can run). They have no further effect on the protection of pages.

You're apparently already aware of the `vm_protect()` function. So why aren't you using that to make the text segment itself writable rather than trying to make the load commands writable?

And it's surely simpler to use `getsegmentdata()` to locate the segment in memory than looking at the load commands (to which you'd have to add the slide).

Beyond that, I would be surprised if iOS lets you do that. There's a general prohibition against run-time modifiable code (with very narrow exceptions).

Comment: There is a reason for it, and that is to make it seem like it has been installed from the app store. This would bypass most anti-piracy checks. Getsegmentdata() would just create a copy of the data, not change the original data that has been loaded into memory

Comment: `getsegmentdata()` returns a pointer to the original loaded data. It does not copy anything. If you do want the segment load command, you could use `getsegbyname()` to obtain its address.

Comment: Of course, @JohnSmith, allowing a program to fake having been installed from the App Store is not something that Apple is inclined to support.  That doesn't mean it's not doable, but I would be a bit surprised.  Not least, I would be surprised if doing it at program runtime were possible, regardless of what segments can be made modifiable.

Comment: Just a hunch, but I imagine `mach_vm_remap()` might work. Build your fake header at compile time, give it its own __TEXT page, then map it over the old one at runtime. Haven't tried, but if that doesn't work, hardly anything else will.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I‘m pretty sure it‘s doable, bc I got it to work a while ago, back on 32 bit devices. I made one extra call or something I guess, but I can‘t remember.      Second, changing cryptid was just an example, I used it to make the question easier to understand.